# Class Initialize() in C#?

Tags: c#

In Obj-c there is the static `Initialize` method which is called the first time that class is used, be it statically or by an instance. Anything like that in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a *static constructor* with the same syntax as a normal constructor, except with the `static` modifier (and no access modifiers):

```
public class Foo {
    static Foo() {
        // Code here
    }
}
```

Usually you don't need to do this, however - static constructors are there for initialization, which is *normally* fine to do just in static field initializers:

```
public class Foo {
    private static readonly SomeType SomeField = ...;
}
```

If you're using a static constructor to do more than initialize static fields, that's *usually* a design smell - but not always.

Note that the presence of a static constructor [subtly affects the timing of type initialization](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx), requiring it to be executed *just* prior to the first use - either when the first static member access, or before the first instance is created, whichever happens first.

Comment: Out of interest, is this a genuine one-off initialisation or is it "once per classloader" like Java. Lookin' good in the hat btw.

Comment: @Bathsheba: It's once per AppDomain, which is a bit like a classloader, but not quite :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity; the OP asks for a *"method which is called the first time that class is used"*, but a static constructor is, as per MSDN, *" called automatically to initialize the class **before** the first instance is created or any static members are referenced."*. Shouldn't we be pointing him to a normal constructor, instead of a static one?

Comment: @DionV.: No, definitely not. Note the "be it statically or by an instance" in the question. A static constructor is call *immediately* before the first use - which sounds exactly like what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `static` constructor.  As per [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx):

`A static constructor is used to initialize any static data, or to perform a particular action that needs to be performed once only. It is called automatically before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced.`

public class Foo
{
    static Foo() {} //static constructor
}

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is called a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx).

By MSDN:

```
public class Taxi
{
    public bool isInitialized;

    //This is the normal constructor, which is invoked upon creation.
    public Taxi()
    {
        //All the code in here will be called whenever a new class
        //is created.
        isInitialized = true;
    }

   //This is the static constructor, which is invoked before initializing any Taxi class
   static Taxi()
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Invoked static constructor");
   } 
}

class TestTaxi
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Taxi t = new Taxi(); //Create a new Taxi, therefore call the normal constructor
        Console.WriteLine(t.isInitialized); 
    }
}

//Output:
//Invoked static constructor
//true
```

Comment: "which is called the first time that class is used, be it statically or by an instance" - what if your `Taxi` class has a static method which we call? No constructor will be called. Additionally, a constructor is called one for each instance, whereas `Initialize` is called once per class.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok, valid point, however I mention the *by an instance* part, and you mention the *be it statically* part, which, as per MSDN, *cannot be called directly.*. Yet, you downvote my question while not having a complete answer yourself. Rude!

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot be called directly"? My point is that the static constructor is called if *either* a static member is called *or* an instance is created, just as the OP wants. As far as I can see, my answer satisfies the OP's requirements, precisely, whereas yours doesn't - or didn't until you added the static constructor part very recently. And it's unclear what your comment of "before initializing any Taxi class" means, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet With that I mean you cannot explicitely call the static constructor. I guess I misinterpreted the OP's question, yet I'm not going to remove my answer since he might find it useful to be provided with the normal constructor part.

Comment: Well it doesn't answer the question that was asked - I suspect it's more likely to confuse both the OP and anyone else who comes to read this later. I would personally delete it in this case, but of course it's your choice.

Comment: In that case, I'd like to hear @Jonny's opinion whether it is useful or not. If not, I will delete it.